# Can't run zf from ps interface

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a working zend framework 2 skeleton application, have added zf2 bin folder to the global windows path variable, yet I cannot run any command starting with zf.

I get the following error message:

`The term`zf`is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`